# Eloquent Relationship returning empty array

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm New to laravel and I'm trying to achieve something very basic stuff but still getting stuck.

I have two models namely Post.php and Like.php

I'm trying to fetch all the likes linked to a post using eloquent relationship but it is returning an empty array. Here is my code-

**Post.php**

```php
public function likes(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}
```

**Route.php**

```php
Route::get('/', function(){
  $posts = Post::all()->sortByDesc("post_id");
  return view('index')->with(['posts' => $posts]);
});
```

**View.blade.php**

```php
@foreach($posts as $post)
  {{ $post->likes }}
@endforeach
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update-**
likes table migration

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('like_id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('post_id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Post Migration**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('post_id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('post_message');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**Post Model**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{

  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }

  public function likes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the `likes` table migration.

Comment: I've added the likes table migration in the update section of the question

Comment: `$table->increments('like_id');` change that to `$table->increments('id');`

Comment: I've changed that to id, but it is still returning the same [] null results

Comment: What's the result of `{{ $post->likes->count() }}`?

Comment: it's returning 0

Comment: though i have got 1 entry in the database

Comment: What's the result of `{{ $post->likes()->toSql() }}`?

Comment: it's returning select * from `likes` where `likes`.`post_id` is null and `likes`.`post_id` is not null

Comment: something is clearly going wrong here. How to get it fixed?

Comment: Please post the `posts` migration and the whole `Post` model.

Comment: I've noticed one thing. When I'm changing my hasMany relationship to `return $this->hasMany('App\Like', 'post_id', 'post_id');`, it is giving the desired result. but i don't know why.

Comment: I've updated my question with the new information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel expects the primary key to be `id`, but you are using the custom `post_id`.

Specify it in your model and adjust the relationship:

```php
class Post extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'post_id';

    public function likes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: this returns an error-  `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'likes.post_post_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Does Laravel pick up on a variable specifically called $primaryKey?

Comment: Yes, you can override the default: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c6ee57c93e6ffa66665b6c66fd936e69e96579ac/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L51